# JSON-LD Missing '}' or object member name. Syntax error: value, object or array expected. How to solved this

Tags: arrays

I tried adding this job posting SD to my HTML I keep getting this

What am I getting wrong

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> [
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "JobPosting",
        "title": "Job1",
        "description": "",
        "datePosted": "2018-10-26",
        "validThrough": "2018-11-02",
        "hiringOrganization": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": {

            }
        }
    },
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "JobPosting",
        "title": "Job2",
        "description": "",
        "datePosted": "2018-10-26",
        "validThrough": "2018-11-02",
        "hiringOrganization": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": {

            }
        }
    }
] </script>
```

[I got this two messages from structured data, how do I fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2LWS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful here.

Comment: try adding a a key value pair inside of the address object